# combining flex display and resizable div browser incompatibilties

Tags: html, css, resize, flexbox

I'm trying to create a standard head, body, footer style `div` using CSS "`display: flex; flex-direction: column;`" inside a resizable `div`.

```css
div {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
  border-color: #999999;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}

.outer div {
  padding: 5px;
}

#cell1 {
  top: 25px;
  left: 25px;
  width: 180px;
  resize:both;
  overflow: auto;
}

#cell2 {
  top: 50px;
  left: 250px;
  width: 180px;
  resize:both ;
  overflow: auto;
}

.outer {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  background: #cccccc;
}

.body {
  flex: 1;
}

.footer {
  background: #cccccc;
}

</style>
```

```html
<meta name="description" content="resizable flex">

<html>

<body>

<div id="cell1" class="outer" onresize="console.log('resized)">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="body">... content here<br>... line 2<br>... line 3</div>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>

<div id="cell2" class="outer">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
  <div>
content here<br>... line 2<br>... line 3</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I've got it working nicely with Firefox, but with Safari and Chrome the left hand `div` is not resizable. Seems like it's the body `div` that's preventing this (the one that is specified to expand) as the right hand box without this resizes fine on Safari and Chrome.

Is this a browser incompatibility, or something wrong the the HTML/CSS?

Comment: please post your code in the question itself...

Comment: Please add your code to the question itself rather than linking to it. We have a useful tool called Stack Snippet that you can choose from the WYSIWYG editor to create a runnable code sandbox for HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to see more on your intent with this to make sure I've created the correct result.

If I understand you correctly, need to add some CSS to some of the other elements, most namely `.footer` within `#cell1`. Here's what that looks like:

```
#cell1 {
  top: 25px;
  left: 25px;
  width: 200px;
  resize:both;
  overflow: auto;
}

#cell1 .footer{
  resize:both;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

And a demo, of course:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qNxRPm

If you need a different type of result, you'll have to tell me more about your use-case or intent.

Comment: OK, great. That works. Allows to resize cell1 with the body part expanding/contracting as needed.
It a bit strange though that you have to set the footer to be resizable, even though that's not the element being resized?